# What movie/series is this toy from?

Tags: story-identification, toys

Whilst cleaning, I discovered this toy.  I believe it was a McDonald's happy meal toy, probably mid to late 1990s, though that's all I've been able to discern.  The toy is approximately 4" high and the blob thing (representation of a magical water attack?) on the front of the shield is spring loaded and shoots out, though the mechanism is broken.

[image: linked thumbnail of the toy in question]

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189711/old-movie-about-a-group-of-friends-with-magical-weapons-fighting-monsters

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That toy is [Angus](http://mysticknightsoftirnanog.wikia.com/wiki/Angus) from the [Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog](http://mysticknightsoftirnanog.wikia.com/wiki/Mystic_Knights_of_Tir_Na_Nog_Wiki). The toys were from 1999.

Here's some pictures of the toy range:

[image: range 1]

[image: range 2]