# Old movie about a group of friends with magical weapons fighting monsters

Tags: story-identification

Alright, so I've been looking everywhere I could think of for just the name of this live-action movie for years. I watched it back around 2003-4.

It starts out with a group of friends throwing disks and "shooting" them with the magic from their weapons. I can remember two of the weapons; a trident with Lightning/electricity, and a sword with fire. The person with the trident was darker in skin tone than the rest and wore mostly blueish colors.

The group goes out on a quest (not sure the reason for it) and they come across monsters on their journey. They end up fighting the monsters one on one (not sure why, the fights happened at different times.)

The monsters I can remember are a Stone monster (fully animated) an Ice monster (more like a human, it speaks in a scratchy voice. Breaks out of the ice when first encountered,) and a sea monster (the man with the trident defeats it).

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: I've never seen the movie, but I read the book.  If it weren't for the timeframe, I'd have guessed [Percy Jackson:  Sea of Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percy_Jackson:_Sea_of_Monsters).

Comment: Live action or Animated?

Comment: Its live action.

Comment: What does "The person with the trident was darker in tone" mean ?  Is that a reference to personality or mood or skin color or what ?

Comment: darker in skin tone, sorry missed that.

Comment: So basically they were shooting skeet at the beginning...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe is not a movie at all, but a TV show called [Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165588/).

It was a Celtic-inspired Power Rangers ripoff that only lasted one season.  The dark-skinned prince character wielded a trident that shoots lightning, while the leader of the group has a flaming sword.

Here's links to the [theme song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxCg26VZ0bQ) and [transformations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76zAU4GxWcE).

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! I only saw it on a VHS tape. Never knew it was a show. Thank you again.